# Decoding OPC-UA extension object

Tags: java, opc-ua

How does one decode extension object obtained from HistoryReadResult to HistoryData type ? I read documentation that suggessts simply using the decode() method but the only variant I can find in the source code is that of decode(EncoderContext).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to mention which stack or SDK you are using, but I can guess that it's the OPC Foundation Java Stack, in which case, you can use `EncoderContext.getDefaultInstance()`. This will work fine with the standard structure types, such as HistoryData. For server specific types, you may need to use a connection specific EncoderContext.